# Selenium WebDriver Script Doesn't Proceed to Next Order After Applying for the First Order

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a Selenium WebDriver automation script in Java to apply for orders on a web app. The script is supposed to navigate to the available orders page, extract order links, click on each order to apply for it, and then return to the available orders page to process the next order.

I have encountered an issue where the script successfully applies for the first order and returns to the available orders page but does not proceed to the next order. Instead, it gets back to the 'available order page' and stops there without any errors on the console.

Here's the code where I am trying to implement the logic, I hope comments will make it easier to understand:
**Code**

```
@FXML
    private void handleStartService(ActionEvent event) {
        // Initialize WebDriver outside the try block

        try {
            // Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\NEWTON\\eclipse-workspace\\WriteDomApplier\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");

            // Initialize the ChromeDriver
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            // Load user settings (subjects, prices, deadlines)
            UserSettings userSettings = loadUserSettings();

            // Check user authentication
            boolean isAuthenticated = checkAuthentication(driver, userSettings);

            if (isAuthenticated) {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                // Retrieve available orders

                Thread.sleep(3000);
                // Extract all order links without relying on the table structure
                List<WebElement> orderLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/dashboard/orders/')]"));

                // Create a Set to track applied order IDs
                Set<String> appliedOrderIDs = new HashSet<>();

                for (WebElement orderLink : orderLinks) {
                    try {
                        // Extract the order ID from the link text
                        String orderId = orderLink.getText();

                        // Check if the order has already been applied for
                        if (appliedOrderIDs.contains(orderId)) {
                            System.out.println("Order " + orderId + " has already been applied for. Skipping.");
                            continue; // Skip to the next order
                        }

                        // Click on the order link to view order details
                        orderLink.click();

                        // Wait for the "APPLY" button to become clickable
                        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                        WebElement applyButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div/div/div/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/button")));

                        // Apply for the order by clicking the "APPLY" button
                        applyButton.click();
                        Thread.sleep(3000);

                        // Add the applied order ID to the Set
                        appliedOrderIDs.add(orderId);

                        // Go back to the Available Orders page for the next order
                        driver.navigate().back();
                    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException staleException) {
                        // Re-identify the order link after a StaleElementReferenceException
                        orderLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/dashboard/orders/')]"));
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (Exception innerException) {
                        innerException.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("Authentication Not Successful");
            }
        } catch (Exception outerException) {
            outerException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Sample HTML Structure of the Order links**

```
<a href="/dashboard/orders/123456">987625</a>
```

**What I've Tried:**

Implementing explicit waits to ensure elements are loaded properly.
Using a Set to track applied order IDs and skip already applied orders.
Handling StaleElementReferenceException to re-identify elements.

**What I'm Trying to Achieve:**

I want the script to apply for each available order and then move on to the next order after applying for the first one, without reopening orders that have already been applied for.

**My Question:**

What could be causing the script to not proceed to the next order after successfully applying for the first order? Are there any potential issues in my code that I might have missed, or is there a better approach to achieve this?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to improve my Selenium WebDriver script to handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you clicking `driver.navigate().back()` and then catching `StaleElementReferenceException` (that is for sure appeared in your case after order processing), your pages has not been rendered yet when you're calling `find_elements`.

Try to wait for at least one element to exist or visible in `catch` block and only then get list of elements.

```java
 } catch (StaleElementReferenceException staleException) {
   // Re-identify the order link after a StaleElementReferenceException
   WebDriverWait wdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   orderLinks = wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/dashboard/orders/')]")));
 } catch (Exception innerException) {
// your code 
}
```

Also, more good appoach is not to catch stale element reference exception, but to loop through elements collection via element index and re-init orderLinks array after `driver.navigate().back();`

I guess your collection length after processing order would be still the same (so you can just go to the next element with index++)

Using this approach you shouldn't handle processed orders (index always would be incremented in next iteration), and your code would be a bit cleaner and shorter.